# Find command not deleting anything when -delete is used

Tags: ubuntu, bash, find, xubuntu

I'm using this script:

```
find $convfold -name \*.mkv -o -name \*.avi -o -name \*.mov -o -name \*.wmv -o -name \*.m4p -o -name \*.m4v -o -name \*.mpg -o -name \*.mp2 -o -name \*.mpeg -o -name \*.mpe -o -name \*.mpv -o -name \*.m2v -o -name *.m4v -delete
```

where `$convfold` is a variable for the folder in which I'm deleting the video.

If I remove the `-delete` from the code it displays the files it should be deleting but when I have it in the code I get no return errors nor exceptions.

Example:

```
flynn@Tron:~/FilebotHandbrake/testconverting$ find -name \*.mkv -o -name \*.mp4 -o -name \*.avi 
./TV Shows/Mr. Robot/Season 02/Mr. Robot - S02E02 - eps2.0_unm4sk-pt2.tc.mkv
./TV Shows/Mr. Robot/Season 02/Mr. Robot - S02E01 - eps2.0_unm4sk-pt1.tc.mkv
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you should use `find "$convfold" …` in case there is a space in the folder path. It has nothing to do with the problem, still it's a good general practice.

Comment: Hint: debug `find` commands, not by *removing* things like `-delete`, but by *replacing them* with `-print`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that, with `find`,  logical-and binds tighter than logical-or.  Observe:

```
$ ls
file1  file2  file3  file4
$ find . -name \*1 -o -name \*2 -exec echo {} \;
./file2
```

In the above, `-name \*2` and `-exec echo {} \;` are bound together with an implied logical-and.  This logical-and binds stronger than the logical-or, `-o`, that connects the first `-name` to the second.

To avoid that, you need to apply parens for grouping:

```
$ find . \( -name \*1 -o -name \*2 \) -exec echo {} \;
./file1
./file2
```

Or, for your complete command:

```
find $convfold \( -name \*.mkv -o -name \*.avi -o -name \*.mov -o -name \*.wmv -o -name \*.m4p -o -name \*.m4v -o -name \*.mpg -o -name \*.mp2 -o -name \*.mpeg -o -name \*.mpe -o -name \*.mpv -o -name \*.m2v -o -name *.m4v \) -delete
```

#### Documentation

From `man find`:

> Please note that `-a` when specified implicitly (for example by two
>   tests appearing without an explicit operator between them) or
>   explicitly has higher precedence than `-o`.  This means that 
>    `find . -name afile -o -name bfile -print`
>   will never print afile.