# Find files from different directories with inclusion and exclusion of some

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell, tail

I want to find files from three different folders with certain files included & excluded.
**Folder 1:**

- Path: /var/www/app/var/log/
- Exclude only: file1.log & file2.log

**Folder 2:**

- Path: /var/log/web/log/
- Include only: error.log

**Folder 3:**

- Path: /var/log/service/log/
- Include only: app1.error.log & app2.error.log

How would I search files from three different folders in this case?

Comment: See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1577902/432690).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks for sharing. In my case, the files are in different top-level directories so.

Comment: Irrelevant. You can specify many starting points in a single invocation of `find` and build an expression (e.g. with `-path`) so different tests are performed for different paths. But even this is irrelevant. A straightforward way is to run three separate `find` commands in sequence. If you tell me you cannot do it after reading the linked answer then I will probably write an answer here that will address your problem directly (or maybe someone will beat me to it).

Comment: Yeah, please. Really appreciated.

Comment: Done. Hopefully the "example variant of the third command that maybe fits your needs better" in my answer below is enough for you to adjust all the three commands on your own. If not, leave me a comment. I may be able to improve the answer, but only after you clarify your needs in the question. Some of the notes in the answer address what needs to be clarified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `find`. Read about general usage of `find` in the context of excluding and including: [*Recursively search files with exclusions and inclusions*](https://superuser.com/a/1577902/432690).

Your problem involves three paths and different requirements for each. One can specify many starting points in a single invocation of `find` and build an expression (e.g. with `-path`) so different tests are performed for different paths. It's possible but rather cumbersome. A straightforward way is to run three separate find commands in sequence.

```
find /var/www/app/var/log ! -name file1.log         ! -name file2.log
find /var/log/web/log       -name error.log
find /var/log/service/log   -name app1.error.log -o   -name app2.error.log
```

Notes:

- Multiple spaces in the above commands are only to emphasize their structure and similarities.
- You say "I want to find files". The above commands will find [files](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690) including files of the type directory; in particular the first command will find its own starting point (`…/log`). To find regular files only you need `-type f`. To find non-directories only you need `! -type d`.
- If `file1.log` or `app1.error.log` is of the type directory then it's not clear if "included" or "excluded" refers to the directory alone or to the directory and everything below. This is probably not an issue because most likely `file1.log` and such are regular files in your setup.

  For the record, each of the above commands traverses the entire directory tree under its starting point. E.g. if `file1.log` is of the type directory then `! -name file1.log` will not stop `find` from testing `file1.log/foo`. To exclude a subtree you need `-prune`.
- `find` works recursively. The simplest way to make GNU `find` not descend into subdirectories is `-maxdepth 1`. Non-GNU implementations may not support it. With purely POSIX `find` [it's not that simple](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275637/108618).

  You tagged [ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu); Ubuntu provides GNU `find` out of the box so use `-maxdepth 1` freely.
- Proper usage of `-o` [is not as straightforward as you may wish](https://superuser.com/a/1119301/432690).
- If there are symbolic links involved, read about `-H` and `-L` options in `man 1 find`. You may want to use one of them.

---

With all this in mind I can craft an example variant of the third command that *maybe* fits your needs better:

```
find /var/log/service/log/ -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -name app1.error.log -o -name app2.error.log \)
```

Or POSIX-ly (to make the answer more useful for a general audience):

```
find /var/log/service/log/. \( -name . -o -prune \) -type f \( -name app1.error.log -o -name app2.error.log \)
```

The last component of the starting point in the latter command ends is `.`. This allows us to use a generic solution (I mean the form `-name . -o -prune` does not depend on the really meaningful part of the starting point path). On the other hand `find` will include `/.` in every pathname, you may not want this.

---

Running three `find`s instead of one does not prevent you from piping the results to a single destination (e.g. `xargs`):

```
{ find … ; find … ; find … ; } | xargs …
```

Note in Ubuntu you can do `find … -print0 | xargs -r0 …`. This is [more robust](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/321753/108618) than `find … -print | xargs …`, not portable though.

Comment: I know that `{}` are magic expansion when used with comma. But how `{}` behaves with `;`? Bit confused

Comment: And thank you for the detailed explaination!

Comment: @MagePsycho `{ }` or `( )` pair [groups commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html). In our case there is no difference between the two because [Bash runs each command in a pipeline as a separate process (i.e., in a subshell) anyway](https://superuser.com/a/1348970/432690).